# Searching AD for a printer using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, search, active-directory, printers

I am using VB.net, trying to query Active Directory to check and see if a printer exists there. I have an AD connection but it doesn't seem to return any values when I run the code. Here is the snippet of my code

```
Dim searchResults As New ArrayList
Dim myDirectorySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(myDirectoryEntry))    
Dim targetObject as string = "printerName"
Dim searchFilter as string = "cn"
Dim strFilter = "(&(objectClass=printer)(" & searchFilter & "=" & targetObject & "))" 

    myDirectorySearcher.Filter = strFilter
    myDirectorySearcher.CacheResults = False

    For i = 0 To searchCriteria.Count - 1
        myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(searchCriteria(i).ToString)
    Next

    Dim mySearchResult As SearchResult = myDirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

Tried various methods but nothing seems to be working, any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do something similar to this with a project I was working on at work. In short, I think you might be searching under the wrong `objectClass` in ActiveDirectory.

Printers *sometimes* get added under `printQueue`.

Your code would then be something like:

```
Dim searchResults As New ArrayList
Dim myDirectorySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(myDirectoryEntry))    
Dim targetObject as string = "printerName"
Dim strFilter = "(&(objectClass=printQueue)(cn=" & targetObject & "))" 

myDirectorySearcher.Filter = strFilter
myDirectorySearcher.CacheResults = False

For i = 0 To searchCriteria.Count - 1
    myDirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(searchCriteria(i).ToString)
Next

Dim mySearchResult As SearchResult = myDirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

It is also worth bearing in mind that sometimes the `printerName` will have the domain appended to the end, so your query may not always return the results you would expect.

For example your printer name may be `PRINTER-RECEPTION` but is referenced on your domain with `PRINTER-RECEPTION.MYCOMPANY.DOMAIN`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: +1, Hello Richard, 
I've got a similar project where I'd have to list out AD printers and add them, I've been able to get the printers successfully and now I'm wondering how I would go about adding/mapping the printer on to the computer, I've tried looking up articles online but all of them speak about adding network printers using WMI ( nothing specific to AD), any references or guidance is appreciated